# Crystal Sub-reports on Citrix

Tags: citrix

We've got a Crystal Report (v8.5 - yes I know it's old!), with contained sub-reports, that gives problems when attempting to run on Citrix (by one of our customers).  This appears to be because the sub-reports retain a hard-coded reference to the location of the original Access database at design time.  The latter is, for example, located at C:\xyz\abc.  Unfortunately we can't fool it by simply copying a dummy Access file to this location, as the Citrix user effectively does not "see" a C: drive!  (At least this is my understanding - it has proven very difficult to find out basic operating principles of the Citrix environment.
Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?
(Or found any sites giving basic guidance to Citrix environment?)

Thanks
Chris L

Comment: You should add crystalreports + ms-access tags

Answer (score 0):

Where is the target access db located? Is it on a network drive somewhere?

I have little to no experience with access db and crystal, but I think you should be able to go "Set Datasource Location" and update the access tables to point at the correct path.

One thing I will say about crystal and citrix is that you shouldn't run different versions of crystal on the same citrix box. It gave us a lot of headaches!

I know the [Citrix forum](http://support.citrix.com/search/forum/?searchQuery=crystal+report&search.x=14&search.y=13&search=Go&categoryId=c150) has helped me more than once...